# Time availability using Moment JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flatpickr

I'm building an appointment scheduler that has a dropdown using Dropdown Select  to select a person. Let's say John Smith and flatpickr to select a date. When I select on John smith he should have an appointment between 3-5pm on Oct 30th. So if I want to display and disable the button he's not available between 3-5pm and display the rest of the buttons with times he is available. How can I go tackle this? Is there a NPM I can install? The times I will be comparing to are from the moment js library. I'm using React Js and the times I'm getting from that person is from an Ajax call.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let id = this.props.userId || this.props.match.params.id

    const promise = userService.getUserIdNetwork(id)
    promise.then(response => {
        const coaches = []
        const coachItems = response.item
        coachItems.map(item => {
            coaches.push({
                value: item.connectionId
                , label: `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`
            })
            this.setState({
                options: coaches
                , requesterId: id
            })
        })
    })
    // array of objects that have start AND end datetimes
    //make the date with the appointment date
    const startAndEndTimes = [
        {startTime: moment().hour(12).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(12).minute(59).second(59)}
      , {startTime: moment().hour(1).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(1).minute(59).second(59)}      
      , {startTime: moment().hour(2).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(2).minute(59).second(59)}      
      , {startTime: moment().hour(3).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(3).minute(59).second(59)}      
      , {startTime: moment().hour(4).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(4).minute(59).second(59)}      
      , {startTime: moment().hour(5).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(5).minute(59).second(59)}      
      , {startTime: moment().hour(6).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(6).minute(59).second(59)}      
      , {startTime: moment().hour(7).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(7).minute(59).second(59)}      
      , {startTime: moment().hour(8).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(8).minute(59).second(59)}      
      , {startTime: moment().hour(9).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(9).minute(59).second(59)}           
      , {startTime: moment().hour(10).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(10).minute(59).second(59)}           
      , {startTime: moment().hour(11).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(11).minute(59).second(59)}           
      , {startTime: moment().hour(12).minute(0).second(0), endTime: moment().hour(12).minute(59).second(59)}           
    ]          
    console.log(startAndEndTimes)
      const promise2 = appointmentsService.getAppointmentByDay(id, 10, 26, 7)
      promise2.then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          response.items.forEach(timeObj => { //loops thru array of items to access appointmentDate by date. Coaches appointments
              console.log(timeObj.appointmentDate)
              debugger;
              let appBegins = timeObj.appointmentDate;
              let appEnds = timeObj.appointmentEndDate;
              // get appEndTime as well

              startAndEndTimes.forEach(arrTime => { // arr of times that will be compared to coaches times range
                  let slotBegins = arrTime.startTime._d
                  let slotEnds = arrTime.endTime._d
                  debugger;

                 if((appBegins > slotBegins) && (appBegins < slotEnds) || (appEnds < slotEnds) && (appEnds > slotBegins)){
                      return console.log("Not Available")
                  }else {
                      return console.log("Available Times")
                  }
              })
              this.setState({
                  dateFromApiCall: response.items
              })
          })

      })
          .catch(console.error)
  }
```

Comment: Also want to add if I select a different date those times will change and the buttons should disable and display the available ones.

Comment: It would be nice if you can share a little code (as relevant as possible) to help us answer you in a way that will actually help you

Comment: I added the code. Sorry if its messy im still a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment-range` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range/v/1.0.2) to create a range of dates and then check if current date is within that range so you can disable the button:

```
const start = moment('2018-10-27 21:40:00');
const end = moment('2018-10-27 22:40:00');
const now = moment();

const range  = moment().range(start, end);

range.contains(now); // Current time is within the range therefore disable button.
```

Comment: Ok ill try this out. Thanks!